# Properties of a Powerset Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $n > 1$ be an integer and $A = \{1, \ldots,n\}$ and consider the graph with vertices

$V = \mathcal{P}(A)$

and edges

$E = \{\{S,T\}:|(S \setminus T) \cup (T \setminus S)| = 1\} $

a) What are the degrees of the vertices in $G$ ?

b) For what values of $n$ is $G$ bipartite?

c) For what values of $n$ does $G$ have an Euler circuit

d) For what values of $n$ is $G$ connected?

Mainly I have been stuck on understanding what the powerset of a graph means. An edge as multiple subsets of a powerset hasn't clicked in my head.

Comment: You were likely downvoted for not showing any of your own effort. What have you tried? What do you think *might* work? Are you struggling understanding how to construct a power set of a graph? Edit the question with this information so that we know where you are getting stuck and how we can best help you.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly build the graphs for $n = 2$ or $n = 3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a graph, where the labels of the vertices are subsets of $A$, and we connect two vertices if they have the same label, but one of them contains precisely one more element. Here is an example where $A=\{x,y,z\}$ (in our problem, it would be $\{1,2,3\}$; also, ignore the arrows):

[image: Power set graph]

Now, it is clear that degrees of the vertices here are all $3$. If we constructed the power set graph of $\{1,2\}$, we would find that all of their degrees are $2$. This should lead us to believe that the degrees of all of the vertices on the power set of $A=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ is $n$.

Let $S\in \mathcal P(A)$ be some vertex of our graph, with $|S|=k$. This means that there are $n-k$ elements in $A$ but not in $S$. Adjoining any *single* of these elements to $S$ would give us an edge of $S$. Moreover, removing any *single* one of the $k$ elements of $S$ would also mean we have an edge of $S$. Therefore, there $S$ must have degree $n-k+k=n$. Since $S$ was arbitrary, all vertices have degree $n$.

Comment: I'll leave it to you to consider the rest of the problems. Each post here should include only one question, so I'd advise you to ask it on another post as such.